# Canon 500D live stream

Tags: video-streaming, video-capture, edsdk

I have a canon 500D and need to stream recordings real time to my pc. I already tried to capture the liveview stream with the EDSDK (in C++) but the quality was to low for my application.

Are there any possibilities to stream a recording of 4MP real time to my pc? I dont think that the EDSDK supports this?

Comment: Is your device shown by Windows as a webcam/WIA? If so, you should be able to capture with a standard video capture program.

Comment: No, I think that these cameara's are never shown as webcam in windows